# Add null's for numerics using CTE in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have some data as below

```
ID Data
1   a
1   2
1   b
1   1
2   d
2   3
2   r
```

Desired Output

```
ID    Data
1     a
1     NULL
1     NULL
1     b
1     NULL
2     d
2     NULL
2     NULL
2     NULL
2     r
```

What the output is , for the numerics it is replaced with those many null values. E.g. for a numeric value of 2 , it will be 2 null values.

The ddl is as under

```
Declare @t table(ID int, data varchar(10))

Insert into @t
Select 1, 'a' union all select 1, '2' union all select 1, 'b' union all select 1, '1'  union all select 2,'d' union all
select 2,'3' union all select 2, 'r'

select * from @t
```

Please give a CTE based solution. I already have the procedural approach but I need to have a feel of CTE  based solution.

Solution I am using at present

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SPLIT] (
 @str_in VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS @strtable TABLE (id int identity(1,1), strval VARCHAR(8000))

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @tmpStr VARCHAR(8000), @tmpChr VARCHAR(5), @ind INT = 1, @nullcnt INT = 0
SELECT @tmpStr = @str_in

WHILE LEN(@tmpStr) >= @ind
BEGIN

 SET @tmpChr = SUBSTRING(@tmpStr,@ind,1)
 IF ISNUMERIC(@tmpChr) = 0
  INSERT INTO @strtable SELECT @tmpChr
 ELSE
  WHILE @nullcnt < @tmpChr
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @strtable SELECT NULL
   SET @nullcnt = @nullcnt + 1
  END
 SELECT @ind = @ind + 1, @nullcnt = 0

END

RETURN

END
GO
```

**Invocation**

```
SELECT * from dbo.SPLIT('abc2e3g')
```

I donot want to do it using function but a CTE solution.

**Reason:** I am learning CTE and trying to solve problems using it. Trying to come out of procedural/rBar approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

```
declare @t table(UniqueID int identity(1,1), ID int, data varchar(10))

insert into @t
select 1, 'a' union all 
select 1, '2' union all
select 1, 'b' union all
select 1, '1' union all
select 2, 'd' union all
select 2, '3' union all
select 2, 'r'
```

Query:

```
;with cte
as
(
    select UniqueId, id, data, case when isnumeric(data) = 1 then cast(data as int) end Level
    from @t
    union all
    select UniqueId, id, null, Level - 1
    from cte
    where Level > 0
)
select id, data
from cte
where Level is null or data is null
order by UniqueID, Level
```

Output:

```
id          data
----------- ----------
1           a
1           NULL
1           NULL
1           b
1           NULL
2           d
2           NULL
2           NULL
2           NULL
2           r
```

I added UniqueId as there should be some kind of field that specifies order in the original table.

Comment: @aditi - seems like you've got the answer already. Let me know if you still have open questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numbers table, this becomes quite simple.

```
;WITH Nbrs ( Number ) AS (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + Number FROM Nbrs WHERE Number < 8000 )
SELECT
   M.UniqueID, M.ID, Data
FROM
   @t M
WHERE
   ISNUMERIC(M.Data) = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
   M.UniqueID, M.ID, NULL
FROM
   @t M
   JOIN  --the <= JOIN gives us (M.Data) rows
   Nbrs N ON N.Number <= CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(M.Data) = 1 THEN M.Data ELSE NULL END 
ORDER BY
   UniqueID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Edit: JOIN was wrong way around. Oops.

Numbers CTE taken from [here](http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/tblnumbers.aspx)

Comment: Different question. You didn't ask that here